# Ruby: how to get data from html table

Tags: html, ruby

I am new to Ruby can someone help me please?

below is my html structure, I want to print 'X01FJ65K0M' from td. There is
no id on this table.

Thanks in advance

```html
<table class="results" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th class="results" style="">
Request Type
</th>

<th class="results" style="">
Agent Type
</th>

<th class="results" style="">
</th>
</tr>
<tr class="results0">
<td style="">

X01FJ65K0M

</td>
<td style="">
07/03/2014 08:14:42
</td>
```

Comment: If there are no id or other attribute, how do you know that you want `X01FJ65K0M` and not `07/03/2014 08:14:42`?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Nokogiri`](http://www.nokogiri.org/) with css selector:

```
html = <<EOS
<table class="results" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th class="results" style="">
Request Type
</th>

<th class="results" style="">
Agent Type
</th>

<th class="results" style="">
</th>
</tr>
<tr class="results0">
<td style="">

X01FJ65K0M

</td>
<td style="">
07/03/2014 08:14:42
</td>
</tr>
</table>
EOS

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
doc.at_css('.results0/td[1]').text.strip
# => "X01FJ65K0M"
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var str = $('table tr td:first').text();
    alert(str);
})
```

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/m5Lrseup/